# Error in writing javascript function using src attribute

Tags: javascript, src

Writing this function

`function updateImage(){
    var img_preview = document.getElementById('img-preview-home').src="\ui\public\live-home\img_preview.png"; 
}`

I have this error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence

Can someone help me???
Thanks.

Comment: It considers `\u` the start of a Unicode escape sequence, https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode You would need to mask the backslash with an additional one - or use forward slashes in the first place, there is no good reason to use the Windows-style backslahes in URLs to begin with.

Comment: yes it's like what CBroe says   , to solve the problem  double the backslash  `"\\ui\public\live-home\img_preview.png"; `